# Max retries exceeded with differents URL in requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, httpconnection, connect-timeout

I have some problems with a script that I am doing to facilitate a process that I have at work. The script consists of listing each website that you have in a txt file, and making another list but with different paths for the URLs

Finally I make a last list, and each element of that list is the web with the path together, for example ('http://web.com/path/')

and lastly I have to go to each web page with requests.get()

and verify that this path does exist in that web page, and I verify that by evaluating the status_code, if the status_code is 200 I add it to a list with the websites that gave a positive result and if not, I only go to the next one.

```
import requests
direccion_archivo = 'webs.txt'
webs_list = []
with open(direccion_archivo) as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:
        webs_list.append(linea.rstrip())


direccion_archivo_02 = 'directorios.txt'
direcs_list = []

with open(direccion_archivo_02) as archivo_02:
    for linea in archivo_02:
        direcs_list.append(linea.rstrip())


urls = []
for web in webs_list:
    for direct in direcs_list:
        link = web + direct
        urls.append(link.rstrip())


AdminPanels_websites = []
for website in urls:
    getweb = requests.get(website)
    SSLWeb = requests.exceptions.SSLError(website)
    
    if SSLWeb is True:
        pass
    if getweb.elapsed.total_seconds() >= 1:
        pass
    if getweb.status_code == 200:
        AdminPanels_websites.append(website)
        print(AdminPanels_websites)
    else:
        pass

with open("paneles.txt", "w") as archivo_03:
    for panel in AdminPanels_websites:
        archivo_03.write(panel.rstrip())
        archivo_03.write("\n")
```

But there is a problem that I don't know how to solve it, when I run the script, everything is fine, but suddenly I get the following errors:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

```
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001836654D9F0>, 'Connection to www.actionplastics.co.za timed out. (connect timeout=None)')
```

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.actionplastics.co.za', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:/products/ (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001836654D9F0>, 'Connection to www.actionplastics.co.za timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

I have investigated about these errors, and it is because I am sending several requests to a URL, but if I am only sending a single request to a single web page, then why do I have this error?

I would like to know what you would do in such cases, I would really appreciate it <3

I have tried with that conditional, I put it in the last part of the code starting from :

```
for website in urls:
    getweb = requests.get(website)
    SSLWeb = requests.exceptions.SSLError(website)
```

and after that, I put:

```
ConnectionWeb = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError(website)
if ConnectionWeb is True:
    pass
```

But it does not work